# get last value from select menu after refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to get last option the user Chosen before the refresh

This is the code select menu:

```
 <select name="category" id="category" onChange="BK.Ajax.Updates('newfile.php?id='+document.getElementById('category').value,'ajx');">
                                <option>.....</option>
                        <?
                        $sql_category=mysql_query("select * from  category");
                        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_category))
                        {
                            echo "<option value='$row[id]'> ";
                            echo $row['name'] ;
                            echo "</option>";
                        }

                        ?>
                        </select>
```

like this example [http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxut/6/]

Comment: Before refreshing the document? Like a F5 or Cmd+R?

Comment: You will have to use $_SESSION or $_GET, $_POST will be emptied after a refresh

Comment: or a simple cookie will do...

Answer (score 0):

In order to save data from previous pages / while moving from one page or another - you will have to use `$_SESSION`.  Sessions are made in order to help to do such things. 
For example, in page a.php you could do the following:

```
    session_start(); //initialize session
    if(!(isset($_SESSION['pageVisited']))){
        $_SESSION['pageVisited'] = 'a';
    }else{
       echo "last page visited is. ".$_SESSION['pageVisited'];
    }
```

You could add the code above to page b.php and change  `$_SESSION['pageVisited'] = 'b';`
and if you the user first entered page a, and then moved to page b - while visiting page b the message "last page visited is a" will be printed.

The session struct is user friendly and pretty easy to handle, for further information read :
http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php 
      if(isset($_POST['category'])){
     $lan = $_POST['category'];
      echo $lan;
      }
      ?>

   or 

   <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['category'])){
   $lan = $_POST['category'];
    sesison_start();
     $_SESSION['lang'] = $lan ;
     echo $_SESSION['lang'];
     echo $lan;
     }
     ?>
```